# xsl table row value do not show or show based on eah other year values

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I will be having xml as below:

```
<catalog>
    <performanceVO>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/1998">1998-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="10.73">10.73</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="4.35">4.35</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/1999">1999-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="97.91">97.91</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="86.54">86.54</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2000">2000-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="46.58">46.58</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="38.15">38.15</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2001">2001-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="-20.48">-20.48</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-25.05">-25.05</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2002">2002-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="-42.48">-42.48</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-45.79">-45.79</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2003">2003-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="43.55">43.55</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="35.28">35.28</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2004">2004-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="11.96">11.96</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="5.53">5.53</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2005">2005-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="5.55">5.55</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-0.51">-0.51</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2006">2006-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="5.03">5.03</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-1.02">-1.02</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2007">2007-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="-1.60">-1.6</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-7.26">-7.26</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2008">2008-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="-10.64">-10.64</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-15.78">-15.78</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2009">2009-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="11.83">11.83</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="5.41">5.41</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2010">2010-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="17.28">17.28</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="10.54">10.54</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2011">2011-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="8.35">8.35</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="2.12">2.12</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2012">2012-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="29.35">29.35</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="21.90">21.9</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2013">2013-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="68.64">68.64</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="58.95">58.95</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2014">2014-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="33.91">33.91</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="26.22">26.22</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2015">2015-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="5.50">5.5</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-0.57">-0.57</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <fAnReVal>
            <fNumber>402</fNumber>
            <rtnDate alt="12/31/2016">2016-12-31</rtnDate>
            <rtnWOSC alt="-17.16">-17.16</rtnWOSC>
            <rtnWSC alt="-21.92">-21.92</rtnWSC>
        </fAnReVal>
        <bmCalYearDet>
               <benchMarkOrder>1</benchMarkOrder>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2016</calYear>
                  <val alt="11.96">11.96</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2015</calYear>
                  <val alt="1.38">1.38</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2014</calYear>
                  <val alt="13.69">13.69</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2013</calYear>
                  <val alt="32.39">32.39</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2012</calYear>
                  <val alt="16.00">16</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2011</calYear>
                  <val alt="2.11">2.11</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2010</calYear>
                  <val alt="15.06">15.06</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2009</calYear>
                  <val alt="26.46">26.46</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2008</calYear>
                  <val alt="-37.00">-37</val>
               </bmCalDet>
               <bmCalDet>
                  <calYear>2007</calYear>
                  <val alt="5.49">5.49</val>
               </bmCalDet>
            </bmCalYearDet>
            <bmCalYearDet>
            <benchMarkOrder>2</benchMarkOrder>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2016</calYear>
                <val alt="-21.68">-21.68</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2015</calYear>
                <val alt="11.42">11.42</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2014</calYear>
                <val alt="34.32">34.32</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2013</calYear>
                <val alt="65.97">65.97</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2012</calYear>
                <val alt="32.29">32.29</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2011</calYear>
                <val alt="12.08">12.08</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2010</calYear>
                <val alt="15.25">15.25</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2009</calYear>
                <val alt="15.84">15.84</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2008</calYear>
                <val alt="-12.56">-12.56</val>
            </bmCalDet>
            <bmCalDet>
                <calYear>2007</calYear>
                <val alt="4.64">4.64</val>
            </bmCalDet>
        </bmCalYearDet>
    </performanceVO>
</catalog>
```

Currently I have issue with my existing logic when there is no particular year node tree from the xml then the values are getting wrongly mapped.

Tabular data:

```
               2016    2015   2014  2013   2012  2011   2010   2009   2008  2007
rtnWOSC/@alt  -17.16   5.5   33.91  68.64  29.35 8.35   17.28  11.83 -10.64 -1.6
rtnWSC/@alt   -21.92  -0.57  26.22  58.95  21.9  2.12   10.54  5.41  -15.78 -7.26
val/@alt      11.96   1.38   13.69  32.39  16    2.11   15.06  26.46 -37    5.49
```

When there is no below node (latest year) for example then the values are getting one td push to left and shows wrongly data of 2015 under 2016

```
<bmCalDet>
      <calYear>2016</calYear>
      <val alt="-21.68">-21.68</val>
</bmCalDet>
```

Below is my XSL:

```
<xsl:variable name="performanceCount" select="count(catalog/performanceVO/fAnReVal)"/>    
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/performanceVO/fAnReVal">
            <xsl:sort data-type="text" select="rtnDate/@alt" order="descending" />

            <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 11">
            <th>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(rtnDate/@alt, 7, 4)" />
            </th>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/performanceVO/fAnReVal">
    <xsl:sort data-type="text" select="rtnDate/@alt" order="descending" />
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 11">
    <td class="text-right">
        <xsl:value-of select="$rtnWOSCValue"/>
    </td>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tr>

<tr>
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/performanceVO/bmCalYearDet">
<xsl:sort data-type="text" select="calYear" order="descending" />
        <xsl:variable name="calValue" select="val/@alt" />
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= $performanceCount">
            <td class="text-right">
                <xsl:sequence select="frk:dash-if-empty($calValue)" />
            </td>

</xsl:for-each>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

It is ok to show as empty value when there  is no node available. Any suggestions/pointers?

I have tried your below approach for opposite requirment, under W3schools(https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) it did not show headings I was able to get variable value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="bmCalDet-by-year" match="bmCalDet" use="calYear" />
<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <xsl:variable name="years">
        <xsl:for-each select="performanceVO/fAnReVal">
            <xsl:sort select="rtnDate" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(position() > 11)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:variable> 
<h6>Years: <xsl:value-of select="$years" /></h6>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$years/fAnReVal">
                <th>
                    <h5>inside</h5>
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your question is tagged XSLT 1.0, yet you use `xsl:sequence` which is only allowed in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Yes Michael, it is XSLT 2.0. Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not understand the logic of your XSLT. Is there any reason why you cannot do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="data-by-year" match="fAnReVal" use="substring-before(rtnDate, '-')" />

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <xsl:variable name="years" select="performanceVO/bmCalYearDet/bmCalDet" />
    <table border="1">
        <!-- header -->
        <tr>
            <th/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$years">
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="calYear" />
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <!-- 1st row -->
        <tr>
            <th>rtnWOSC</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="$years">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('data-by-year', calYear)/rtnWOSC" />
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <!-- 2nd row -->
        <tr>
            <th>rtnWSC</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="$years">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('data-by-year', calYear)/rtnWSC" />
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <!-- 3rd row -->
        <tr>
            <th>val</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="$years">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="val" />
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the (rendered) result will be:

[image]

If you remove a `fAnReVal` node, the corresponding cells will be empty. For example, using the same input without this part:

```
    <fAnReVal>
        <fNumber>402</fNumber>
        <rtnDate alt="12/31/2016">2016-12-31</rtnDate>
        <rtnWOSC alt="-17.16">-17.16</rtnWOSC>
        <rtnWSC alt="-21.92">-21.92</rtnWSC>
    </fAnReVal>
```

will result in:

[image]

---

Note that this assumes there is at most one `fAnReVal` node per year.

---

### Added:

To do this in the opposite direction - i.e. create the columns from the 10 most recent `fAnReVal`nodes - you could do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="bmCalDet-by-year" match="bmCalDet" use="calYear" />

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <xsl:variable name="catalog" select="." />

    <xsl:variable name="years">
        <xsl:for-each select="performanceVO/fAnReVal">
            <xsl:sort select="rtnDate" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() le 10">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:variable> 

    <table border="1">
        <!-- header -->
        <tr>
            <th/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$years/fAnReVal">
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(rtnDate, '-')" />
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <!-- 1st row -->
        <tr>
            <th>rtnWOSC</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="$years/fAnReVal">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="rtnWOSC" />
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <!-- 2nd row -->
        <tr>
            <th>rtnWSC</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="$years/fAnReVal">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="rtnWSC" />
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <!-- 3rd row -->
        <tr>
            <th>val</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="$years/fAnReVal">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('bmCalDet-by-year', substring-before(rtnDate, '-'), $catalog)/val" />
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for checking on it but the scenario is when we do not have complete year node structure (example complete 2016 node structure is not available under xml) then data get one <td> to left which will result in mismatch

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you're saying. If you don''t have *any* data for 2016, then there will be no column for 2016. If that's not what you want, then please clarify.

Comment: That's correct when there is no data then there is no column is the issue, when there is no complete <fAnReVal> and it's childs for year 2016 but we have data for <bmCalDet> of year 2016 then there will be mismatch of columns which results in left push one column for <fAnReVal>. Hope it's clear. If still unclear then I will try to share with examples.

Comment: I think my second example shows clearly that there will be no "mismatch of columns".

Comment: But your assumption is there would be at most one fAnReVal node per year but the scenario is there would be no fAnReVal node for 2016 year

Comment: @user3669116 "At most one" includes zero. If the above doesn't work for you, please edit your question and add an example showing how it fails (i.e. input + expected output vs. actual output).

Comment: I have tried earlier code fails, I believe it has issue with key declaration. <xsl:key name="data-by-year" match="fAnReVal" use="substring-before(rtnDate, '-')" /> doesn't work. Do I need inlcude any dependency of it ? It throws error as Local variable $key has not been allocated a stack frame slot

Comment: I got it, I will try the approach you have shared and share results. Thank you.

Comment: It works! Thanks, Michael. But instead of empty cells how do add m-dash (-) to it so that it will be meaningful.

Comment: @user3669116 Define a variable as `<xsl:variable name="data" select="key('data-by-year', calYear)" />` then use `<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$data">` to output either the data or text.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. That was helpful.

Comment: Hi Michael, table heading should have year values from fAnReVal since it has more than 10 years and always will have these years in xml. bmCalDet years we may have or we may  not in xml. I have tried to use key as <xsl:key name="data-by-year" match="fAnReVal " use="substring(rtnDate/@alt, 7, 4)" /> then to get data  for-each loop and td <xsl:value-of select="key('data-by-year', rtnDate/@alt)/rtnWOSC" /> but it was not returning desire output

Comment: Hi Michael, table heading should have year values from fAnReVal since it has more than 10 years and always will have these years in xml. bmCalDet years we may have or we may  not in xml. I have tried to use key as <xsl:key name="data-by-year" match="fAnReVal " use="substring(rtnDate/@alt, 7, 4)" /> then to get data  for-each loop and td <xsl:value-of select="key('data-by-year', rtnDate/@alt)/rtnWOSC" /> but it was not returning desire output

Comment: @user3669116 In your example, you have `fAnReVal` data for years 1998 - 2016. Do you want to have a column for each one of these? If not, what is the cut-off point?

Comment: exactly it has data till 1998, will need maximum latest 10 years columns of fAnReVal.

Comment: I was able to get years headings from fAnReVal <xsl:variable name="perfYears" select="performanceVO/fAnReVal" />
    <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$perfYears">
   <xsl:sort data-type="text" select="rtnDate/@alt" order="descending" />
                <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 11">
    <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(rtnDate/@alt, 7, 4)" />
                </th>
    </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr> but could not get the logic to get table data values <td>

Comment: @user3669116 See the addition to my answer.

Comment: I have tried your below approach for opposite requirment, under W3schools for same xml it did not show headings I was able to get variable value. I have added new xsl code approach under same above description.

Comment: @user3669116 Please pay attention: the added stylesheet requires a processor that supports XSLT 2.0. It says so in bold.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Now at third row, it breaks I have tried with xsl 2.0 at http://xslttest.appspot.com/ (example 4 xslt 2.0). It is breaking with the line <xsl:value-of select="key('bmCalDet-by-year', substring-before(rtnDate, '-'), $catalog)/val" />

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment, it is working smoothly. I will try to integrate with my xsl code and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I have updated my xml, while I'm trying to integrate this logic with my xsl code, there is one more condition needs to handle. There are two <bmCalYearDet> tree node which differs with node <benchMarkOrder>. When I loop and use the code as <xsl:value-of select="key('bmCalDet-by-year', substring-before(rtnDate, '-'), $catalog)/val" /> I'm getting two values. Tried filtering it with node <benchMarkOrder> but couldn't able to filter. Can you please provide the pointers?

Comment: I don't think I can provide ongoing support in these comments. I suggest you roll your question back to what it was when I answered it and ask a new one.